# Create VLAN number based on the current last VLAN number

Tags: ansible

I would like to create new VLAN based on the last number of existing VLANS. For example my last VLAN number on the eos is 100 so I would like to run my playbook and create VLAN 101. However when I run my playbook it looks like set_fact iteration is not in order and playbook created for me VLAN 15 instead VLAN 101.

Even I am using sort filter it looks like asnible is not doing iteration in order. Does anyone know how to do it?

My playbook

```
- name: CHECK VLAN
  hosts: eos
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: CHECK FOR VLAN NUMBERS
      eos_command:
        commands: show vlan | json
        provider: "{{ cli }}"
      ignore_errors: yes

      register: sh_vlan_output
    - debug: var=sh_vlan_output.stdout[0].vlans.keys()

    - name: SET VLAN NUMBER
      set_fact:
        vlan_index: "{{ item | int +1 }}"
      with_items:
        -  "{{ sh_vlan_output.stdout[0].vlans.keys() | sort }}"
    - debug: var=vlan_index


    - name: CREATE VLAN
      eos_config:
        lines: 
          - vlan {{ vlan_index }}
        provider: "{{ cli }}"
        authorize: yes



PLAY [CHECK VLAN] **************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [eos-1]

TASK [CHECK FOR VLAN NUMBERS] **************************************************
ok: [eos-1]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [eos-1] => {
    "sh_vlan_output.stdout[0].vlans.keys()": [
        "11", 
        "10", 
        "13", 
        "12", 
        "14", 
        "1", 
        "100"
    ]
}

TASK [SET VLAN NUMBER] *********************************************************
ok: [eos-1] => (item=10)
ok: [eos-1] => (item=1)
ok: [eos-1] => (item=100)
ok: [eos-1] => (item=11)
ok: [eos-1] => (item=12)
ok: [eos-1] => (item=13)
ok: [eos-1] => (item=14)

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [eos-1] => {
    "vlan_index": "15"
}

TASK [CREATE VLAN] *************************************************************
changed: [eos-1]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
eos-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `max + 1` with the following jinja expression:

```
{{ sh_vlan_output.stdout[0].vlans.keys() | map('int') | max + 1 }}
```

Comment: I does not work like this get following error:


`TASK [SET VLAN NUMBER] *********************************************************
fatal: [eos-1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "template error while templating string: no filter named 'map'. String: {{ sh_vlan_output.stdout[0].vlans.keys() | map('int') | max + 1 }}"}`

Comment: Oh, man... how old is your setup? :) Please update Jinja python package to 2.7+

Comment: I have recent package:

`pip show Jinja2
Name: Jinja2
Version: 2.6
Summary: A small but fast and easy to use stand-alone template engine written in pure python.
Home-page: http://jinja.pocoo.org/
Author: Armin Ronacher
Author-email: armin.ronacher@active-4.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires:`


And still the same error

Comment: You have jinja ver. 2.6, but need 2.7 or newer.

Comment: `Name: Jinja2
Version: 2.9.5
Summary: A small but fast and easy to use stand-alone template engine written in pure python.
Home-page: http://jinja.pocoo.org/
Author: Armin Ronacher
Author-email: armin.ronacher@active-4.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Jinja2-2.9.5-py2.7.egg
Requires: MarkupSafe`

I updated to the latest one and still the same error

Comment: `Name: Jinja2
Version: 2.9.5
Summary: A small but fast and easy to use stand-alone template engine written in pure python.
Home-page: http://jinja.pocoo.org/
Author: Armin Ronacher
Author-email: armin.ronacher@active-4.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Jinja2-2.9.5-py2.7.egg
Requires: MarkupSafe`

/br
I updated to the latest version and still the same error. I would like to convert string to integer but not sure how to do it.

Comment: I guess your ansible installation uses python that has different Jinja library. Check you paths. `map` filter is definitely available in Jinja 2.9.